# Slickgrid column reordering is not holding the same position after the page reload. How to hold the same position for the columns in slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

Assume i have multiple columns and  i am going to swap the columns to perform some operation which could reload the page. How to reload the page with same slick grid column position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `6pac/SlickGrid` fork, you need to save the grid state before you leave the page and then call `grid.setColumns(reoderedColumns)` but what would be easier is to use the `Slick.State` Plugin [slick.state.js](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/plugins/slick.state.js) which is used in this [Example - Plugin State](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example-0070-plugin-state.html)

The Example was missing from the [Wiki - Examples](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples), I added it [Example Grid State](https://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-0070-plugin-state.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used the localStorage feature to store the reordered columns.